# Typescript: How to disable transform Omit into Pick, when using generic?

Tags: typescript, tsc

How to disable this behavior? Its a critical when you compile type declarations only for library

I need it for compile declarations only:

```
tsc --declaration true --emitDeclarationOnly true
```

---

Minimal code example:

```
function test<T>(t: T): Omit<T, 'href'> {
  return t;
}

export const TEST_CONST = test({} as HTMLAnchorElement);
```

Expected:

```
export declare const TEST_CONST: Omit<HTMLAnchorElement, 'href'>
```

Recieved:

```
export declare const TEST_CONST: Pick<HTMLAnchorElement, "toString" | "search" | "normalize" | "host" | "password" | "origin" | "hidden" | "dir" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "text" | "blur" | "click" | "focus" | "scroll" | "attributes" | "after" | "animate" | "accessKey" | "className" | "contentEditable" | "draggable" | "id" | "lang" | "tabIndex" | "translate" | "prefix" | "inputMode" | "download" | "href" | "ping" | "rel" | "target" | "type" | "referrerPolicy" | "name" | "charset" | "coords" | "hreflang" | "relList" | "rev" | "shape" | "addEventListener" | "removeEventListener" | "accessKeyLabel" | "autocapitalize" | "innerText" | "offsetHeight" | "offsetLeft" | "offsetParent" | "offsetTop" | "offsetWidth" | "spellcheck" | "assignedSlot" | "classList" | "clientHeight" | "clientLeft" | "clientTop" | "clientWidth" | "localName" | "namespaceURI" | "onfullscreenchange" | "onfullscreenerror" | "outerHTML" | "ownerDocument" | "scrollHeight" | "scrollLeft" | "scrollTop" | "scrollWidth" | "shadowRoot" | "tagName" | "attachShadow" | "closest" | "getAttribute" | "getAttributeNS" | "getAttributeNames" | "getAttributeNode" | "getAttributeNodeNS" | "getBoundingClientRect" | "getClientRects" | "getElementsByClassName" | "getElementsByTagName" | "getElementsByTagNameNS" | "hasAttribute" | "hasAttributeNS" | "hasAttributes" | "hasPointerCapture" | "insertAdjacentElement" | "insertAdjacentHTML" | "insertAdjacentText" | "matches" | "msGetRegionContent" | "releasePointerCapture" | "removeAttribute" | "removeAttributeNS" | "removeAttributeNode" | "requestFullscreen" | "requestPointerLock" | "scrollBy" | "scrollIntoView" | "scrollTo" | "setAttribute" | "setAttributeNS" | "setAttributeNode" | "setAttributeNodeNS" | "setPointerCapture" | "toggleAttribute" | "webkitMatchesSelector" | "baseURI" | "childNodes" | "firstChild" | "isConnected" | "lastChild" | "nextSibling" | "nodeName" | "nodeType" | "nodeValue" | "parentElement" | "parentNode" | "previousSibling" | "textContent" | "appendChild" | "cloneNode" | "compareDocumentPosition" | "contains" | "getRootNode" | "hasChildNodes" | "insertBefore" | "isDefaultNamespace" | "isEqualNode" | "isSameNode" | "lookupNamespaceURI" | "lookupPrefix" | "removeChild" | "replaceChild" | "ATTRIBUTE_NODE" | "CDATA_SECTION_NODE" | "COMMENT_NODE" | "DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE" | "DOCUMENT_NODE" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC" | "DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING" | "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE" | "ELEMENT_NODE" | "ENTITY_NODE" | "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE" | "NOTATION_NODE" | "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE" | "TEXT_NODE" | "dispatchEvent" | "getAnimations" | "before" | "remove" | "replaceWith" | "innerHTML" | "nextElementSibling" | "previousElementSibling" | "childElementCount" | "firstElementChild" | "lastElementChild" | "append" | "prepend" | "querySelector" | "querySelectorAll" | "oncopy" | "oncut" | "onpaste" | "isContentEditable" | "onabort" | "onanimationcancel" | "onanimationend" | "onanimationiteration" | "onanimationstart" | "onauxclick" | "onblur" | "oncancel" | "oncanplay" | "oncanplaythrough" | "onchange" | "onclick" | "onclose" | "oncontextmenu" | "oncuechange" | "ondblclick" | "ondrag" | "ondragend" | "ondragenter" | "ondragexit" | "ondragleave" | "ondragover" | "ondragstart" | "ondrop" | "ondurationchange" | "onemptied" | "onended" | "onerror" | "onfocus" | "ongotpointercapture" | "oninput" | "oninvalid" | "onkeydown" | "onkeypress" | "onkeyup" | "onload" | "onloadeddata" | "onloadedmetadata" | "onloadstart" | "onlostpointercapture" | "onmousedown" | "onmouseenter" | "onmouseleave" | "onmousemove" | "onmouseout" | "onmouseover" | "onmouseup" | "onpause" | "onplay" | "onplaying" | "onpointercancel" | "onpointerdown" | "onpointerenter" | "onpointerleave" | "onpointermove" | "onpointerout" | "onpointerover" | "onpointerup" | "onprogress" | "onratechange" | "onreset" | "onresize" | "onscroll" | "onsecuritypolicyviolation" | "onseeked" | "onseeking" | "onselect" | "onselectionchange" | "onselectstart" | "onstalled" | "onsubmit" | "onsuspend" | "ontimeupdate" | "ontoggle" | "ontouchcancel" | "ontouchend" | "ontouchmove" | "ontouchstart" | "ontransitioncancel" | "ontransitionend" | "ontransitionrun" | "ontransitionstart" | "onvolumechange" | "onwaiting" | "onwheel" | "autofocus" | "dataset" | "nonce" | "hash" | "hostname" | "pathname" | "port" | "protocol" | "username">;
```

---

Explicit type declaration will work, but inconvenient for large chains of function calls:

```
function test<T>(t: T): Omit<T, 'href'> {
  return t;
}

export const TEST_CONST: Omit<T, 'href'> = test({} as HTMLAnchorElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's expected and a valid value. Because `Omit` is a `Pick` with `Exclude`.

```js
/**
 * Construct a type with the properties of T except for those in type K.
 */
type Omit<T, K extends keyof any> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

try to define own type for it.

```js
type NoHref<T> = Omit<T, 'href'>;

function test<T>(t: T): NoHref<T> {
  return t;
}

export const TEST_CONST = test({} as HTMLAnchorElement);
```

Comment: Own type will still be extracted

Comment: Of course, that's what `Omit` does. It doesn't hide anything, just a nice type in IDE `NoHref< HTMLAnchorElement>` instead of `Pick` bla bla.

Comment: if you want to display a nice name alias instead of an ugly resolved type it won't work.

Comment: you last note is wrong, it will be Pick anyway: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gCQE4QGYB4AqA+KBeKAeQFsBLYLAGigHIALFVG7AbgCg3UBXAOwGNgpODyjAIAZwo4AFMABcUTAEoF8ZGiy4A3myhQUwLkhHB2AXw4QAHmDhJgUPsMmKAogGVMAfQDChGJ4KJOToCJgAsgAyAIL8dHauADYQxBA8wNT0jMz4ohLA0lpmUACG4lBhUbF88UhJKWnASuxAA

Comment: I need to emit nice name alias when using `tsc --declaration true --emitDeclarationOnly true`

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: Different dependencies versions between my library and user's project. Example for React component:
```
Type '{ children: string; fullWidth: true; href: string; target: string; theme: "fill_primary"; size: "M"; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, "style" | ... 263 more ... | "referrerPolicy">, "title" | ... 261 more ... | "referrerPolicy">': translate, css
```

Comment: In this case I think you need to play with min TS version of the defs should work with. Because Omit was introduced in a late TS2, or since TS3, I don't remember exactly and earlier versions don't support it. For exmple in ng-mocks all the keys are defined manually to fix this issue (they are not all keys, just a min set that covers all versions): https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks/blob/master/lib/mock-render/mock-render.ts#L12-L38